# IO exceptional handling (Parameter is not valid)

Tags: c#

This is the piece of code i have wriiten. It takes images from the directory and pixel matched it. When the program read 5 images from the directory of same pixels it wor completely fine but when we increase the number of images or images with different pixels it throws the exception  "Argumentexcepton was unhandled". Please help

```
string[] image_name = new string [1000] ;
check = d.GetFiles("*.jpg").Length;
while (imageArray < check)
        {
        double percentage = 0;
        count1 = 0;
        count2 = 0;
        progressBar1.Value++;
        //error occurs on this line
        img2 = new Bitmap(image_name[imageArray]);
        progressBar1.Maximum = check;
        if (img1.Width != img2.Width && img1.Height != img2.Height)
          {
            if (img2.Width > img1.Width || img2.Height > img1.Height)
                {
                img1 = ResizeBitmap(img1, img2.Width, img2.Height);
                }
            else
                img1 = ResizeBitmap(img1, img2.Width, img2.Height);
          }
            for (int i = 0; i < img1.Width; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < img1.Height; j++)
                {
                    img1_ref = img1.GetPixel(i, j).ToString();
                    img2_ref = img2.GetPixel(i, j).ToString();
                    if (img1_ref != img2_ref)
                    {
                    count2++;
                    break;
                    }
                    count1++;
                }
            }
            percentage = (count2 + count1);
            percentage = count1 / percentage;
            percentage = percentage * 100;
            if (percentage < 90)
              {
msg1 = "Sorry, Images are not same , " + count1 + " same pixels found and " +     count2 + " wrong pixels found";
    }
            else if (percentage == 100)
            {
                msg1 = " Images are same , " + count1 + " same pixels found and " + count2 + " wrong pixels found";
               ResultImagePanel rmp = new ResultImagePanel(image_name[imageArray],         Convert.ToString(percentage) + "%", folderPath + "\\" + image_name[imageArray], msg1);
                rmp.Location = new Point(0, 345 * counter);
                panel1.Controls.Add(rmp);
            }
            else
            {
                msg1 = " Similar images , " + count1 + " same pixels found and " + count2 + " wrong pixels found";
                ResultImagePanel rmp = new ResultImagePanel(image_name[imageArray],  Convert.ToString(percentage) + "%", folderPath + "\\" + image_name[imageArray], msg1);
                rmp.Location = new Point(0, 345 * counter);
                panel1.Controls.Add(rmp);
            }
            counter++;
            imageArray++;
}
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`image_name[imageArray]` is `string.Empty` when that code is executed. Hence the error. You will need to fill in the `image_name` array with valid file names, before executing the code.

Comment: i have already done this. Thanks for your help but error still exist

FileInfo[] Files = d.GetFiles("*.jpg");                                                   
foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
            {
                image_name[i] = file.Name;
              
              i++;
            }

Answer (score 0):

Implement your array image_name like this :

image_name =  Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.jpg").ToArray();

Comment: folderPath = @"C:\Users\Fahim Akbar\Downloads\Projects\working\working\bin\Debug\Data Base Images";

DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(folderPath);                     //Assuming images is your Folder
FileInfo[] Files = d.GetFiles("*.jpg");                      //Getting Image files
           //check = d.GetFiles("*.jpg").Length;
            image_name = Directory.EnumerateFiles(folderPath, "*.jpg").ToArray();

Comment: Check permissions of your folder

Comment: still not solved. I should repeat that if the path has five images then its working perfectly fine. But if i increase the images to 6 or more it is throwing exception